# A warm label for a feedback button

Tags: copywriting

Hopefully, this is an appropriate question, if not, I'll delete it. I'm working on a new feature and it's been decided that we will include a slideout feedback panel, similar to [Hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/).

[image]
[image]

Currently, the label is 'Feedback' and it's accompanied by a speech bubble icon.
[image]

I personally don't think the label is clear enough, so I'm looking for alternatives. I've seen both 'Give feedback' and 'Send feedback' used on other sites, but those labels feel a bit impersonal.

Comment: I think 'Feedback' works. The icon however will depend on what the button does. A chat icon should be used if this opens a chat box. If it means help in general, then question mark icon will suit better. And so on...

Comment: Hey @Ren, thanks for responding. I've replaced the chat icon with a chevron. Makes more sense as the panel slides in and out.

Comment: "What do you think?"

Answer (score 0):

"Feedback" is most likely the best way to label said button. If you want to think outside of the box and be even more personal you can replace it with something like "How can we do better?" or "How can we improve?". The problem is that this will need more space.

Comment: "We'd love your feedback" would be friendlier, but, again, space...